# How to change an img width depending on img height

Tags: jquery, image, resize, height, width

I need to change img width depending on img height.
I used the jQuery height property but it doesn't work. Please see my function below.

```
$(function imagesSizer(){
    var img = document.getElementsByClassName('.offer_img');
    if  ($('.offer_img').height() < 210) {
         $('.offer_img').css('width','360px')
    }
});
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work." What do you expect to happen, what really happens, and what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I have image with 1200px width, i can't change this size but i need to fit this img to 310x210 box. But, if some image that i will load does have less than 210 height i need to resize it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You have now answered "What do you expect to happen." Can you help us with the remaining parts? What really happens? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: nothing happens, the img still have 1200px width, i need to change img width to 310px depending on image height ...

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski How is it dependent on the image height? Your current code only changes the width if the height is **less than** 210 pixels, which seems like it's probably wrong to me.

Comment: i need to do exactly this feature, when img height is more than 210px  img width is 310px, when img height is less than 210px need to change it on 210px and 310px width...

Answer (score 5):

You should try

```
//Wait until the DOM is ready
$(function(){
    //get all images and iterate over them
    $('.offer_img').each(function(){;
        //if the height of this img is < 210
        if  ($(this).height() < 210) {
            //set the width to 360
             $(this).width(360);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('.offer_img');
```

to

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('offer_img');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: While you're correct, that line has absolutely no relevance to the rest of the code and should just be removed entirely.

Answer (score 0):

For a single element,

```
$( function(){
    if ( $('.offer_img')[0].height() < 210 )
        $('.offer_img').width(360);
});
```